# CTE рекурсия, не понимаю как работает

Tags: sql-server, рекурсия, дерево, списки, inner-join

Хочу организовать связь многие-ко многим в одной таблице.
Задача. Имеется детали, которые могут входить в сборочные единицы.
Так же сборочные единицы могут входить в более сложные сборочные единицы,
туда же могут входить и детали.

Например **винт**, **гайка**, **шайба**, основание входят в состав сборки под именем **ОСНОВАНИЕ**
**винт**, **гайка**, **крышка** входят в состав сборки **панель**.

И **винт**,**основание**,**панель** входят в состав **корпус**

задача- найти иерархическое дерево всех компонентов, входящих в состав корпуса и панели.

Табличка представляет следующий вид.

RelationID, ProductID(деталь или сборка которая входит), ToProductID(куда входит)

В табличке следующие данные

```
1   1   5
2   2   5
3   3   5
4   4   5
5   5   6
6   6   7
7   1   7
8   2   7
9   3   7
```

Для построения иерархии для изделия 7 использован следующий код.

```
WITH CTE(ProductID, ToProductID) AS 
(
SELECT ProductID, ToProductID FROM Relations WHERE ToProductID = 7
UNION ALL
SELECT     j.ProductID, j.ToProductID
FROM         CTE AS CCTE INNER JOIN
Relations AS j ON CCTE.ProductID = j.ToProductID
)
SELECT     ProductID, ToProductID FROM CTE AS CTE1
```

Код выводит нормальное дерево

```
6   7
1   7
2   7
3   7
5   6
1   5
2   5
3   5
4   5
```

Вот только не могу понять, как он работает(по моим понятиям не должен).
Как я понимаю.

Первый вызов SELECTа ставит якорь, откуда будут продолжаться дальнейшие запросы
`SELECT ProductID, ToProductID FROM Relations WHERE ToProductID =7`
Это RelationID=6

А вот дальше по идее ProductID никогда не равен ToProductID
`CCTE.ProductID = j.ToProductID`- Не должно исполняться, а все
успешно работает.
Как в таком случае работает INNER JOIN если равенства нет, или я его не вижу.
Подскажите, как работает данная конструкция.

Comment: [вот здесь подробно описано как работает рекурсия в CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

> Это RelationID=6

Первая ошибка. Не только `6`, но ещё и `7`, `8` и `9`. Ваша база рекурсии состоит из 4 строк.

> А вот дальше по идее ProductID никогда не равен ToProductID

Вторая ошибка. Вас, видимо, запутали одинаковые названия колонок, но здесь важно заметить, где колонки находятся:

```
SELECT j.ProductID, j.ToProductID -- j!
FROM CTE AS CCTE            -- предыдущий шаг рекурсии
  INNER JOIN Relations AS j -- откуда выбираются записи
          ON CCTE.ProductID = j.ToProductID
```

**Шаг рекурсии** выбирает записи **из всей таблицы `Relations`**. `INNER JOIN` отбирает из них те, что "нужны" (в вашем предметном смысле) для результатов предыдущего шага рекурсии в `CTE AS CCTE`.

- Выбираются детали "следующего уровня" от базового, с `ToProductID` равными `6`, `1`, `2` или `3` (`ProductID` из базы рекурсии). Совпадает всего одна строчка, `5  5 [6]`.
- Выбираются детали "следующего уровня" от прошлого шага, с `ToProductID` равным `5`. Совпадают `RelationID` с `1` по `4`.